# Не удается понять, как превратить txt-файл в строку в Scala

Tags: scala

В универе дали задание. Необходимо удалить определенные символы из текстового файла. Я нашел, как это сделать со строкой, но я не понимаю, как прочитать txt-файл и превратить его в строку.

Нашёл где-то такой метод, но в итоге типом переменной text является что-то другое, но не string

`val text = Source.fromFile(имя_файла)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На удивление не нашел похожего вопроса. Это делается в одну строку:

```
val fileContents: String = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.mkString
```

После `Source.fromFile(filename)` можно указать кодировку: `(Codec.UTF8)`.
Также Source принято закрывать:

```
val fileContents: String = Using(Source.fromFile(filename)(Codec.UTF8)) { _.getLines.mkString }.get
```

Источник: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-open-read-text-files-in-scala-cookbook-examples/ .
Там же есть и про запись в файл: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-write-text-files-in-scala-printwriter-filewriter/